# WordPress Rewrite Condition with Rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added a new rewrite rule in functions php file

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '.*?\/?(less|img|js|css|icons|fonts)\/(.*)',
    'wp-content/themes/theme_name/$1/$2',
    'top'
);
```

How can I add a specific condition? Does wordpress support mod rewrite conditions?
The final result (.htaccess) after saving the permalinks should be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*?\/?(less|img|js|css|icons|fonts)\/(.*) /folder_name/wp-content/themes/theme_name/$1/$2 [QSA,L]
```